# SSMS only keeps loading and then goes to Not Respoding state

Tags: sql-server, database, ssms

I recently updated my computer to latest Windows 10 April 2018 upgrade.

After which I am facing few issues when working with SSMS v17.6 (Its updated to latest version)

Whats happening here is I have a SQL Server Database hosted on Azure and I am trying to access this database.

I am able to connect to the database and after that if I click on Table in my database to expand them and see all the tables it keeps browsing and then goes into Not Responding state and a message pops up saying that Time Out error. I increased the time out limit still I am facing same issue.

This was not happening before Windows update

Also I have couple of more database which I tried connecting and that is working all good.

**Update:
Tried Downgrading to v17.5 still facing the issue**

Comment: There is an alert on the page regarding some crashes in 17.6 [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017) maybe try uninstalling 17.6 and use 17.5 and see if the problem is related to that bug?

Comment: That is for Maintenance Plan. I am not doing anything of that.

Comment: Alright, sounds like you've got it solved. Good luck!

Comment: Its not solved. Still facing same issue actually. And I also tried downgrading as you suggested, but still no change.

Comment: Are you able to connect to the same Azure database from a different machine? That will rule out the problem on your own computer vs the server itself.

Comment: It is working on another computer. But that is not updated to latest Windows 10 April 2018 release.